# Format decimal localizated and formated

Tags: asp.net, internationalization

The example explains the question

expected : **17,590**

First try:

```
const decimal value = 17.59m;
const string format = "{0:0,000}";
var result = string.Format(format, value);
```

This will result `0,018` of course because the culture is en-US and `,` is interpreted as thousand separator.

Second try:

```
const decimal value = 17.59m;
var result = Convert.ToString(value, CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("pt-BR"));
```

Now I get `17,59`

How can I merge format and localization using asp.net framework features?

Comment: You are not doing any parsing here (that is getting a `decimal` from a string), but _formatting_ getting a string representation of a `decimal`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call `ToString` directly on the `decimal` value - it has overloads that take format strings and a `CultureInfo` object.

Note that in a numeric format string the decimal separator is represented as a `.` (which will get converted to the appropriate decimal separator).

This:

```
var result = 17.59m.ToString("0.000", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("pt-BR"));
```

Produces:

```
17,590
```

Comment: Thanks, the optional was hiding the ToString with parameters.